# What happens when you reverse bias a NMOS with separate body terminal?

Tags: mosfet, analog, current-limiting, bias, parasitic-capacitance

I am trying to create a current limiting circuit with minimal output capacitance.

I'm trying to build a circuit that optimises low parasitic output capacitance over linearity.

I used a SST215 DMOS device which features a separate bulk terminal and use the drain terminal as the output since it is the one with the lowest capacitance (1.1pF). The behaviour of Id for Vs>0V is as I expected, but when Vs goes below 0V the Id behaves like a diode with varying forward voltage. Can anyone explain what is happening here? How does this depend on the gate-voltage/bulk-voltage?

[image: My setup with the sst215 controlling the current into the DUT via Vg]

My setup with the sst215 controlling the current into the DUT via Vg. For characterization of the MOS behaviour the resistance of the DUT was 0 Ohms

[image: Measuring the Id dependence of the MOSFET by setting the Bulk to the lowest potential (-10V) and capture a I-V plot of Idrain vs. Vsource with different gate voltages.]

Measuring the Id dependence of the MOSFET by setting the Bulk to the lowest potential (-10V) and capture a I-V plot of Idrain vs. Vsource with different gate voltages. The Current is limited by the voltage source to 10mA protect the device in case of some pn junction shorting the device. The behavior for Vs<0V is what I didn't expect.

[image: A more detailed measurement with Vg between 2V and 3.4V, same setup.]
A more detailed measurement with Vg between 2V and 3.4V, same setup.

Comment: Try measuring the curves again holding Vgs (not Vg) constant. With Vs < 0 and becoming more -ve, Vgs is increasing, turning the FET on. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Those MOSFETs are in principle symmetrical like JFETs between drain and source, i.e. there will be no reverse conduction, and they work as a regular switch.

In fact, a few leftover analog switches are still sold with only an NMOS and not CMOS pair. The advantage is faster switch time and lower capacitance.

In your experiment, the gate-body area is always at least at +10V so in strong inversion (i.e. 'on'). Current will flow unless you pinch off the source area for V_gs < 3 V. If you bring the source negative enough, it will also conduct, and the whole transistor channel can conduct.

**For more "expected" behavior, apply gate voltage with respect to the body potential.** I.e. The off state (bidirectionally blocking) should be V_g = -10 V and it will start to conduct bidirectionally at V_g ~ -7 V *if* the gate is also at least 3 V positive wrt source/drain.

However, when you bring the source to close to that gate potential, it will start to block again. Therefore, if you want to keep it fully on, apply V_g ~ +10 V

Answer (score 0):

> *The behaviour of Id for Vs>0V is as I expected, but when Vs goes below
> 0V the Id behaves like a diode with varying forward voltage. Can
> anyone explain what is happening here?*

Yes, with Vg at 0 volts, as Vs falls more negative, it produces a net gate-source voltage that turns on the MOSFET. Your circuit must keep Vg close to Vs whenever the device is meant to be non-conducting. In other words, you need to redesign your gate control circuit so that the gate voltage follows the source voltage; it can either be the same (producing non-conductivity) or it can be higher by several volts (producing conductivity between source and drain).

Maybe consider using a PV opto-isolator: -

[image]

Pin 4 connects to source and pin 6 connects to gate. Pins 1 and 3 are your on/off signal.